# How to debug SAQL Logs in Einstein Analytics dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am getting one issue in my Analytics Dashboard. The percentage calculations are going beyond 100 (the result is coming as 34,795.04%). I want to debug the SAQL.
[Enable SAQL Logs in the Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_logs.htm)
I have tried the above solution but I am not able to enable the logs.

Can you guys please help me how can I get the debug logs in Analytics?

Thanks

Nirav Shah

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dashboard Inspector to get the SAQL queries instead.  Below are the steps to use Dashboard Inspector to see a SAQL query.

1. Put the Dashboard in View Mode (not Edit mode)
2. Click the [...] icon beside the save button and select 'Dashboard Inspector'
3. Select the Step which contains the SAQL query
4. Click the icon which looks like a piece of paper to view the SAQL query for that step.

Also check details on debugging Einstein Analytics [here](https://salesforce-trailblazer.com/debugging-einstein-analytics/).